# System of two non-linear differential equations with two variables and initial conditions

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, derivatives, partial-differential-equations

I'm trying to approach two solutions for the next system of equations with two variables:
$$\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2} = \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{b} (x -\frac{(1-a)(x+a)}{((x+a)^2+y^2)^{3/2}}-\frac{a(x-1+a)}{((x+a)^2+y^2)^{3/2}}) \\
\frac{1}{b} (y -\frac{(1-a)y}{((x+a)^2+y^2)^{3/2}}-\frac{ay}{((x+a)^2+y^2)^{3/2}})  \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
Which follows the next two equations within all variables coupled:

$$\ddot{x} = \frac{1}{b} (x -\frac{(1-a)(x+a)}{((x+a)^2+y^2)^{3/2}}-\frac{a(x-1+a)}{((x+a)^2+y^2)^{3/2}});\\
\ddot{y} = \frac{1}{b} (y -\frac{(1-a)y}{((x+a)^2+y^2)^{3/2}}-\frac{ay}{((x+a)^2+y^2)^{3/2}});$$
Modifying both equations to a non-linear second-order differential equations:
$$\ddot{x} +  \frac{1}{b} (-x +\frac{(1-a)(x+a)}{((x+a)^2+y^2)^{3/2}}+\frac{a(x-1+a)}{((x+a)^2+y^2)^{3/2}}) = 0;\\
\ddot{y} + \frac{1}{b} (-y +\frac{(1-a)y}{((x+a)^2+y^2)^{3/2}}+\frac{ay}{((x+a)^2+y^2)^{3/2}}) = 0;$$
The initial conditions are:
$$x(0) = -340; \\
y(0) = 80; \\
\dot{x}(0) = 0;\\
\dot{y}(0) = -0.7;$$

The problem I find here's is how the two variables can be separated and solve the second derivative of each variable, I tried by change of variables, but it didn't get to any place.
The change of variables to another coordinates is a good way to solve it, or there is another theorem or method to solve it.

Comment: If you tell us the numeric values of $a$ and $b$ one could try a numerical solution.